# XV6 locking of process table in scheduler

Tags: operating-system, xv6

I'm confused about the acquire and release relating to the lock on the *ptable* used in the function below (`yield()` from proc.c).

My instructor says the lock on **`ptable`** is acquired to avoid race conditions with other CPUs that might access the **`ptable`** concurrently, but I'm confused as to why the lock is only released at the end here.

Doesn't that mean the new process is run for its entire time slice before the lock is released and other CPUs can use the **`ptable`**?

```c
void yield(void)
{
  acquire(&ptable.lock);
  cp->state = RUNNABLE;
  sched();
  release(&ptable.lock);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider 2 processes, P1 and P2. P2 had yielded and now you are in P1.

Now inside P1 you are calling yield(). Let's take this as your above starting point.
From `yield()` after acquiring `ptable.lock`, `sched()` is called and inside `sched()`, you'll find the following statement:

`swtch(&p->context, mycpu()->scheduler);`

This will switch from your current process's context to scheduler context.
When I say that, what happens is it'll continue from the `switchkvm()` below inside `scheduler()`

As you can see after that `ptable.lock` is released. Next it will find a `RUNNABLE` process and switch to it.So in a process of switching, the execution inside `scheduler()` below has happened till calling `swtch(&(c->scheduler), p->context);`

Whenever P2 yields, it'll take ptable.lock and call sched(). Inside sched(), swtch will be called and context of scheduler() will be switched to. Inside scheduler(), it'll start from switchkvm().

**So the `ptable.lock` acquired during context of the process inside `yield()` is released inside `scheduler()`.**

PS: Pardon my English. I am not a native speaker.

Below is the code snippet from https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/proc.c

```
void
scheduler(void)
{
  struct proc *p;
  struct cpu *c = mycpu();
  c->proc = 0;
  
  for(;;){
    // Enable interrupts on this processor.
    sti();

    // Loop over process table looking for process to run.
    acquire(&ptable.lock);
    for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++){
      if(p->state != RUNNABLE)
        continue;

      // Switch to chosen process.  It is the process's job
      // to release ptable.lock and then reacquire it
      // before jumping back to us.
      c->proc = p;
      switchuvm(p);
      p->state = RUNNING;

      swtch(&(c->scheduler), p->context);
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This is where a context switch continues from.
      switchkvm();

      // Process is done running for now.
      // It should have changed its p->state before coming back.
      c->proc = 0;
    }
    release(&ptable.lock);

  }
}
```